# Can't cast ixmlnode to other interface inheriting from ixmlnode

Tags: xml, delphi, interface, casting

I'm trying to make a structure with an interface so I can do x = A.B instead of A.ChildNodes['B']. Problem is, it's giving me an EIntfCastError each time I try to cast the childnode to the relevant interface.

```
unit TestXML;
interface
uses
    Winapi.Windows,
    Winapi.Messages,
    System.SysUtils,
    System.Variants,
    System.Classes,
    Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls,
    Vcl.Forms,
    Vcl.Dialogs,
    Xml.XMLDoc,
    Xml.XMLIntf,
    Vcl.StdCtrls;
type
    IXMLKmehrHeaderType = interface(IXMLNode)
        ['{4FC29DEE-A5A8-4F8E-AE59-6EB42F966B2D}']
    end;
    TXMLTransactionResponseType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLNode)
    protected
        function Get_Response: IXMLNode;
        function Get_Acknowledge: IXMLNode;
    public
        procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    end;
    TXMLKmehrHeaderType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLKmehrHeaderType)
    end;
    IXMLGetTransactionListResponseType = interface(IXMLNode)
        ['{D07A4789-034A-4EEF-80FE-11EB95EB5124}']
        function Get_KmehrHeader: IXMLKmehrHeaderType;
        property KmehrHeader: IXMLKmehrHeaderType read Get_KmehrHeader;
    end;
    TXMLGetTransactionListResponseType = class(TXMLTransactionResponseType, IXMLGetTransactionListResponseType)
    protected
        function Get_KmehrHeader: IXMLKmehrHeaderType;
    public
        procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    end;
    TTest = class(TForm)
        btnTest: TButton;
        txtXML: TMemo;
        procedure btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
    private
        { Private declarations }
    public
        { Public declarations }
    end;
var
    Test: TTest;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
{ TXMLTransactionResponseType }
procedure TXMLTransactionResponseType.AfterConstruction;
var
    prefix: string;
begin
    inherited;
    prefix := FindNamespaceDecl('http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/hubservices/core/v3').LocalName;
    RegisterChildNode(prefix + ':ackknowledge', TXMLNode);
    RegisterChildNode(prefix + ':response', TXMLNode);
end;
function TXMLTransactionResponseType.Get_Acknowledge: IXMLNode;
begin
    Result := ChildNodes['ackknowledge'] as IXMLNode;
end;
function TXMLTransactionResponseType.Get_Response: IXMLNode;
begin
    Result := ChildNodes['response'] as IXMLNode;
end;
{ TXMLGetTransactionListResponseType }
procedure TXMLGetTransactionListResponseType.AfterConstruction;
var
    prefix: string;
begin
    inherited;
    prefix := FindNamespaceDecl('http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/hubservices/core/v3').LocalName;
    RegisterChildNode(prefix + ':kmehrheader', TXMLKmehrHeaderType);
end;
function TXMLGetTransactionListResponseType.Get_KmehrHeader: IXMLKmehrHeaderType;
var
    prefix: string;
begin
    prefix := FindNamespaceDecl('http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/hubservices/core/v3').LocalName;
    Result := ChildNodes[prefix + ':kmehrheader'] as IXMLKmehrHeaderType;
end;
procedure TTest.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    doc: IXMLDocument;
    Test: IXMLGetTransactionListResponseType;
    header: IXMLKmehrHeaderType;
    prefix: string;
begin
    doc := LoadXMLData(txtXML.Text);
    Test := doc.GetDocBinding('GetTransactionListResponse', TXMLGetTransactionListResponseType, 'http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/hubservices/protocol/v3') as IXMLGetTransactionListResponseType;
    prefix := Test.FindNamespaceDecl('http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/hubservices/core/v3').LocalName;
    header := Test.KmehrHeader;
end;
end.
```

I expect to be able to cast a childnode to TXMLKmehrHeaderType.
Each time though, I get the exception EIntfCastError with message Interface not supported.'

Please help, been trying to solve this problem all day.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns4:GetTransactionListResponse 
        xmlns="http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/standards/kmehr/id/v1" 
        xmlns:ns2="http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/hubservices/core/v3" 
        xmlns:ns3="http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/standards/kmehr/schema/v1" 
        xmlns:ns4="http://www.ehealth.fgov.be/hubservices/protocol/v3">
        <ns2:response/>
        <ns2:acknowledge/>
        <ns2:kmehrheader/>
    </ns4:GetTransactionListResponse>

Comment: added xml document (reduced in size for readability)

Comment: You might take a look at  https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2009/08/22/querying-for-the-implementing-object-from-an-interface-2/.

Comment: I am not enough of a COM expert to know for sure but this sounds v. similar to the problem described on p.50 of Eric Harmon's 'Delphi COM Programming' book.  This used to be available online at googlebooks but doesn't seem to be anymore.  Anyway, he says the solution to the "interface not supported" is to use TAggregatedObject or an alternative proposed by Hallvard Vossbotn in his blog, so try googling for those.  Interesting q, btw, +1.

Comment: Figured out what the problem was in mean time, when trying to bind my interface to the xml document, he only binds the interface to the top element in the xml document. There is no recursive binding down the xml structure like I hoped it would.